# Progress bar for loading large Pickle objects?

Tags: python, progress-bar

I'm currently using the [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) Python library to output a pretty progress bar for loops. I was wondering, would there be either a built-in or a third-party way of outputing a progress bar for loading a large object?

Right now I have code that looks like:

```
with open('some_pickle.pkl', mode='rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(file=f)
```

and have attempted to use `tqdm` as:

```
with open('some_pickle.pkl', mode='rb') as f:
    obj = tqdm(pickle.load(file=f), desc='Loading large object')
```

but there's no output.

Would anyone be kind enough to provide some feedback on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you control the pickle file?

Comment: I'm assuming that I cannot. If there were to be a way to "control" the Pickle file, then would it be possible to create a progress bar for the loading process?

Comment: I imagine you could use clever `__reduce__` tricks to observe the unpickling process, although it might be difficult to place them very uniformly throughout the processing.

Answer (score 2):

with `tqdm`, You can't. It only works with iterables with **len**() property. It's `hard/impossible` to know how far you are through pickling/unpickling an object.

Comment: There could however be a nice feature request to optionally use tqdm e.g. for the specific case that the object being pickled/unpickled is a list, which would meet the requirement for many use cases even if not all